# "I'm not a Robot" Recaptcha is not working as expected -Selenium WebDriver(Java)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, recaptcha

**Steps to Produce:**

1. I am trying to handle "Recaptcha" through manual intervention using Selenium Web Driver (Java) in Firefox Browser
2. In the demosite,"https://demoqa.com/register", I am trying to automate "Recaptcha" through manual intervention
3. I am switching into "I'm not a Robot" frame and trying to click on the checkbox and then use "Explicit Wait" till I manually click on "Verify" button
4. Then I am switching out of the iframe to the default content and trying to click "Register"

**Issue:**

1. My code works till switching into "I'm not a Robot" frame and the random image tiles open, then it doesn't work

**My Code:**

```
//Check "I'm not a Robot"
    driver.switchTo().frame(7);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='recaptcha-anchor']/div")).click();
    
   
    
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(15));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(
            By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@name, 'a-4fg5nocuvnax') and starts-with(@src, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha')]")));
   
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("#recaptcha-verify-button"))).click();
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Help me and correct if I am wrong .

Comment: Do you get same result with selenium 3.x.x?

Comment: I did not try with selenium 3 , i am trying this in Selenium 4